# $\nabla\left(\nabla \boldsymbol{r}_{0} e^{i \boldsymbol{k} \boldsymbol{r}} e^{-i \omega t}\right) $- meaning?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, differential-geometry, notation, vector-analysis

My physics professor wrote the following equation:
$$
\nabla\left(\nabla \boldsymbol{r}_{0} e^{i \boldsymbol{k r}} e^{-i \omega t}\right)=-e^{-i \omega t} e^{i \boldsymbol{k r}} \boldsymbol{k}\left(\boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}_{0}\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{k}$ is a general $k$-vector and $r=[r_x,r_y,r_z]^T$ a cartesian vector. Can someone explain how the right-hand side is obtained from the left-hand side? Usually $\nabla$ is used to denote the gradient, but calculating the gradient of the gradient of $\boldsymbol{r}_{0} e^{i \boldsymbol{k r}} e^{-i \omega t}$ does not lead to the expression on the right-hand side.

Comment: If $k$ and $r$ are scalars, then $\frac{d^2}{dr^2} e^{ikr} = (ik)^2 e^{ikr} = -k^2 e^{ikr}$. I suspect this can be generalized to the case when $k$ and $r$ are vectors.

Comment: What exactly is the data-type of the expression supposed to be? Is the gradient of the gradient a matrix in this context?

Comment: The equation above is a part of a longer derivation. He is skipping many steps, so it is a bit difficult to follow, but the end result is a tensor.

Comment: The expression should be $$\nabla\left(\nabla \cdot \left(\vec r_0 e^{i \vec k\cdot \vec r}e^{-i\omega t}\right)\right)$$Is that correct?

Comment: @MarkViola, I was suspecting that too. So the gradient of the divergence, right?

Comment: Yes.  Grad Div .

Comment: Is this class electromagnetism by any chance? Sometimes you have different coordinate systems at play, where, depending on notation, subtle prime symbols are used to denote the nabla operator for each system. tldr: Are you remembering all subscripts and prime symbols?

Comment: @WilliamBarnes, the class is quantum optics. But my teacher also wrote the continuity equation using the gradient operator instead of the divergence operator as it should be. So probably Mark Viola is correct.